# Can't run any commands downloaded in python virtual env

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I've been using python3.10 with no problem through the virtual environment, but now I've hit some weird roadblock.  Whenever I try to run one of the commands I've installed through pip, it gives me an error like this:

```
$ jupyter-lab
-bash: /Users/{pathing}/venv/bin/jupyter-lab: /Users/{pathing}/venv/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However, inside my venv/bin folder, they're clearly there:
[my bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngsyO.png)

Not sure what's causing this exactly.  I'm running MACOS 12.1.